# storing object value in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am getting some object values in python which I want to store in mongodb for later use, but with no luck

```
def callPylink(self):
    from pylinkgrammar.linkgrammar import Parser
    import sys
    p = Parser()
    linkage = p.parse_sent("When was Gandhi born")
    try:
        print "Linkage 0 ", linkage[0]
    except:
        print "error"
    self.collection.insert(linkage[0].__dict__)
```

at insert line:

```
Linkage 0 <pylinkgrammar.linkgrammar.Linkage object at 0x92db84c>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "objmongo.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = obj.callPylink()
  File "objmongo.py", line 23, in callPylink
    self.collection.insert(linkage[0].__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 409, in insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.uuid_subtype, client)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <S: When, was>
```

what is other way to store python object in mongo.

**update**

```
    pickled = pickle.dumps(linkage[0])
    self.collection.insert(pickled)
```

gives error:

```
  File "objmongo.py", line 30, in <module>
    data = obj.callPylink()
  File "objmongo.py", line 25, in callPylink
    self.collection.insert(pickled)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 409, in insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.uuid_subtype, client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 386, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: what does `linkage[0]` return?

Comment: @Michael: it return pylink object as given in result\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store a dictionary in mongodb, your dictionary can only contain string keys and those types of values that mongodb can serialize (encode). This is not the case here.

You can serialize complex object trees into byte strings and deserialize them back using the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, use `pickle.dumps(obj)` to serialize an object into a bytestring, and `pickle.loads(bytestring)` to deserialize the object

Example: given the following class and instance

```
>>> class OurClass():
...     def __init__(self, arg):
...         self.arg = arg
... 
>>> instance = OurClass(42)
```

we import the pickle module

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(y)
>>> pickled
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nX\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00argq\x03K*sb.'
```

the `pickled` is the value to store into database *in a field of a document*, like:

```
my_doc = { 'linkage': pickled }
self.collection.insert(my_doc)
```

Now you can restore the original value with `pickle.loads`

```
>>> restored = pickle.loads(pickled)
>>> restored
<__main__.OurClass object at 0x7fc91cb35cf8>
>>> restored.arg
42
```

Comment: thanks, but getting different error, can you please check update

Comment: @nlper please provide *full* stack traceback **always**

Comment: yes because the result is a string that is not possible to use as a mongodb *document*, only a field.